# Angular 6 - Reactive form selection option - Database data versus selection list options

Tags: angular6

I have a selection option field that should display the value for the formControlName field from the database and should provide a list of options to choose from.

In this case, it is a project manager who is no longer in the business unit. He will not be listed in the object used for the list of options available in the selection list because he has been transferred to another business unit. His information should still be displayed in the formContralName field though.

His information is available in the formControlName field. I have used a text input field to verify that the information is available and displayed.

The source of the list is a table which is updated through a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) task from information recorded in an ERP system. So, any transfers within the company will be synchronized to the system by the SSIS.

This form is used for creating new records, reading and updating existing records.

How can I continue to display historic information (the previously selected project manager) while also providing a list of current options while using a selection option field?

I am looking forward to hearing from.

```
<label for="selectSpm" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm oms-label">SPM<i class="fa fa-question-circle" [popover]="popoverSpm" Preconfigured popover></i></label>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-7 oms-textual" style="font-size: 12px;" id="selectSpm" formControlName="senior_proj_man" title="Select the SPM from the list">
    <option value="" disabled>Select SPM</option>
    <option *ngFor="let spm of spms" [value]="spm.spm">{{ spm.dir + " - " + spm.spm }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make (the previously selected project manager) part of an API and you should call this API when you will view this form and in you component when you build the form you should do the following

```
this.API_SERVICE.METHOD().subscribe(data => {
  if(data is available) {
    this.buildform(data);
  }
});

buildform(data) {
YOUR_FORM = new FormGroup({
  senior_proj_man: new FormControl(data.(previously selected project manage));
 })

}
```